# Multiprocessing file output significantly slower

Tags: python

I am trying to improve performance on a script that parses data from large text files (1-100gb). I thought I would give multiprocessing a go to see if that would speed things up. As far as I can tell the processes are starting fine, but it is around 3x slower than saving without multiprocessing.

The multiprocessing version:

```
from multiprocessing import Lock, Process
from datetime import datetime

def worker(mylist, count):
    outFile = str(count) + '.txt'
    out = open(outFile,'w')
    for i in mylist:
        out.write(i)           

def main():
    ##    lock = Lock()
    startTime = datetime.now()
    jobs = []
    tempList = []
    count = 0
    inFile = open('batch1.kscsv','r')
    for line in inFile:
        if('Traversal' in line and len(tempList) == 0):
            traversalString = line
        if('Traversal' not in line and 'Spot' not in line and 'XValue' not in line):
            line = line.replace(',',' ')
            tempList.append(line)
        if('Traversal' in line and len(tempList) > 0):
            spotFromFile = (traversalString.split(',')[1]).strip()
            count += 1
            p = Process(target=worker, args=(tempList, count,))
            p.start()
            tempList = []
            traversalString = line

    print ('Run took: ' + str((datetime.now()-startTime)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The regular script:

```
from datetime import datetime      

def main():
    startTime = datetime.now()
    jobs = []
    tempList = []
    count = 0
    inFile = open('batch1.kscsv','r')
    for line in inFile:
        if('Traversal' in line and len(tempList) == 0):
            traversalString = line
        if('Traversal' not in line and 'Spot' not in line and 'XValue' not in line):
            line = line.replace(',',' ')
            tempList.append(line)
        if('Traversal' in line and len(tempList) > 0):
            spotFromFile = (traversalString.split(',')[1]).strip()
            count += 1

            outFile = str(count) + '.txt'
            out = open(outFile,'w')
            for i in tempList:
                out.write(i)

            tempList = []
            traversalString = line


    print ('Run took: ' + str((datetime.now()-startTime)))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Is this a problem that is just not well suited for multiprocessing? Or is there a way to improve the multiprocessing?

Comment: Coud you upload your `batch1.kscsv` file somewhere so I can test it on my machine.

Comment: @laike9m The file is basically repeating of xy coordinates like:                                                                                               Traversal Index,256
XValue:DALTONS,YValue
2998.18398466268,0.01116455
2998.43673408455,0.01067383
2998.68949776728,0.01160645
2998.94227571129,0.01089355
2999.19506791702,0.01139648
2999.44787438491,0.01166748
2999.70069511539,0.01152344
2999.95353010889,0.0110791

Answer (score 0):

Using multiple processes will help you with tasks that are CPU bound. In this case, the function that you are delegating simply opens a file and writes to it. This will probably be mostly IO bound, and you just have more processes in contention for the disk resources.

Moreover, there is a fairly high cost to forking, which will slow things down even more. Using a process pool rather than creating a new process for every call would be much more efficient since the setup is only done once per process in the pool.

```
def worker(mylist, count):
    outFile = str(count) + '.txt' # a few variable and string operations, CPU, fast
    out = open(outFile,'w') # system call, won't benefit from multiprocessing much, slow
    for i in mylist: # increment a counter, CPU, fast
        out.write(i) # write to file, IO, slow
```

And here:

```
# forking, fixed cost, expensive, adds work for the kernel in tracking COW or consumes lots of memory depending on OS.
p = Process(target=worker, args=(tempList, count,))
p.start()
```

Multiprocessing will start to be beneficial if the worker function actually has to do a lot of work on the input. Tree searches, computations, etc. Once again though, it would be beneficial to have a fixed number of processes operating off a queue rather than to spawn a new process for every analysis (unless there are few of them).

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So the task is just not well suited for multiprocessing given it isn't CPU intensive.

Comment: That's basically it. The IO and three `if ... in ...` are probably the most time consuming, and they're outside the multiprocessing. For scanning millions of lines, using else if rather than a string search and starting with the most likely case probably can save you some time instead.